# How do I pop the drawer widget safely in flutter

Tags: flutter, routes

I have a side drawer with a menu of target pages. When I click on one of the menu items, the app should close the drawer and open the target page.

Should I call `Navigator.of(context).pop()` to close the drawer and in the next line  call `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(.....)` ?

Since I have already popped the drawer widget, will it create problems if there is any code after pop()? It sounds logical that the side drawer should not be on the page stack once its works is done. The code works fine without calling pop(). But If do not pop the drawer at all, will there be any memory leaks or similar issues?

Edit:

I think my question was not clear. I am asking about how Flutter maintains a stack of pages and navigates from one to another: it pushes a new page on top of the currently active page; when the page completes its work, Flutter pops it out and reveals the old page.

In my case, the 'old page' is a side Drawer widget. It contains a menu of all available pages. When the user chooses a page, the drawer widget has to be popped. There are 3 ways in which this can be done.

case 1:
Never pop the drawer. Just navigate to the new page. In pseudo code:

```
navigateToNewPage();
```

case 2:

```
  navigateToNewPage();
  popTheDrawer();
```

case 3:

```
 popTheDrawer();
 navigateToNewPage();
```

In case (1), what happens to the drawer widget on the page stack? Does it sit there like a ghost consuming resources, or will Flutter automatically remove it? If the user opens the drawer 10 times, will 10 copies of the drawer occupy the page stack?

In case (2), the user may go the new page and do many things, navigating to other pages, visiting web sites etc. Finally when and how they should return and execute the line `popTheDrawer()`?

In case (3), When the drawer widget is already popped and gone, it is safe to execute any more code on it? As an extreme example, will you put twenty lines of code after the line `popTheDrawer()`?

Comment: Not sure why the negative vote; my question is about Flutter internals.  I am not confused  about how to navigate to another page from my drawer. That part is already working fine. But my concern is about freeing up memory resources used by the drawer. Is popping the widget mandatory to remove it from the page stack and free up resources, or I can just abandon it and navigate away?

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts are you shouldn't use `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(.....)` or `Navigator.of(context).pop()` either. Just use the normal  `Navigator.push(context,NextPage()).then((value) {Navigator.of(context).pop();})`

Here you'll be routed to the next page and when navigating back, the drawer will be closed.

Comment: Thanks, but the nextPage may want to navigate to a thirdPage, from there go to a fourthPage etc.  The flow is really non-linear and unpredictable to my drawer widget.

Answer (score 0):

use both

```
Navigator.of(context).push()
```

and

```
Navigator.of(context).pop
```

It will redirect you to new page and also pop up dialogue box